# Como fazer uma instância da amazon EC2 escutar a porta 5000 via HTTP?

Tags: node.js, amazon-aws

Uma instancia EC2 Ubuntu que tem instalada NodeJS com uma app que responde na porta 5000 com o comando node.

Iniciei o NodeJS `node app.js` através do terminal (ssh) e tentei acessar pelo browser através de `meupublicDNS:5000` mas não funciona.

Não consegui configurar a porta 5000 no security group. Como fazer para configurar essa porta?

Comment: Você tentou configurar o inbound rule do seu security group criando um custom TCP apontando pra porta 5000 e permitindo o range 0.0.0.0/0 no source?

Comment: exato... deu certo. posta la sua resposta.

Comment: Feito, sucesso!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure o Inbound Rule do seu Security Group como **Custom TCP** na porta 5000, adicione também o range 0.0.0.0/0 no Source para liberar o acesso de qualquer ip na sua aplicação.

Comment: Parece que vc manja muito sobre Amazon services. Eu estou aprendendo. me adiciona ai no seu facebook. https://www.facebook.com/igoralves1